# Como capturar uma foto através da webcam do usuário e enviar via POST?

Tags: javascript, html5

Como realizar o procedimento de captura de imagem da webcam do usuário em um formulário de cadastro para enviar via `POST`? Busco por uma solução que seja compatível com a maioria dos navegadores e que seja de simples implementação.

Comment: De uma olhada nesse tutorial: [http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/228-How-to-Use-a-Webcam-to-take-Pictures-in-PHP-Application.html](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/228-How-to-Use-a-Webcam-to-take-Pictures-in-PHP-Application.html)

Comment: Este link tem um boa explicação em portugues:
<http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/>

Comment: Do meu ponto de vista a única maneira de ser o mais compatível com vários Browsers seria usar as soluções em html5 já demonstradas e acaso o browser não de suporte, usar uma solução alternativa em Flash (apenas para capturar a imagem).

Comment: Conseguistes resolver tua questão? Não encontrou a resposta?

Comment: Um adendo: Agora seu site precisa ter [conexão https para para poder acessar a Webcam via HTML5](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95282/getusermedia-agora-ser%C3%A1-depreciado-em-conex%C3%B5es-n%C3%A3o-https?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 25):

***Exemplo Mínimo***

***PHP***

`camera.php`

```php
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tirar Fotos</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
        video { border: 1px solid #ccc; display: block; margin: 0 0 20px 0; }
        #canvas { margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div><video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video></div>
    <div><button id="snap">Tirar Foto</button></div>
    <div><button id="save">Salvar Foto</button></div>
    <div><canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas></div>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        video = document.getElementById("video"),
        videoObj = { "video": true },
        errBack = function(error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
        };  
        if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                video.src = stream;
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }
        else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {      
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);       
        //alert(canvas.toDataURL());
    });
    document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {      
        $.post('fotossalvar.php', {imagem:canvas.toDataURL()}, function(data){
        },'json');
    });
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

`fotossalvar.php`

```php
<?php
    function base64_to_jpeg( $base64_string, $output_file ) {
        $ifp = fopen( $output_file, "wb" ); 
        fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $base64_string) ); 
        fclose( $ifp ); 
        return( $output_file ); 
    }       
    $imagem = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,','',$_POST['imagem']);        
    base64_to_jpeg($imagem, "pasta1/foto1.png");        
    echo json_encode(array('imagem' => 1));
```

Todo o código se resume nesses dois arquivos, siga esse modelo como fator de teste. Configure a sua aplicação com jQuery, e uma pasta com o nome de `pasta1`, sendo tudo feito em HTML5 com PHP.

Em relação aos navegadores, o *Google Chrome* e o *Firefox* funcionaram perfeitamente, já o *IE* não tive sucesso.

***Fontes:***

- [Camera and Video Control with HTML5](http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera)
- [HTML5 Canvas Save Drawing as an Image](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/)

Answer (score 11):

Existe um projeto muito interessante no GitHub com vista a fornecer uma solução atual para o uso da webcam do cliente, fazendo uso de fallback para Flash em casos de navegadores mais antigos:

### [WebcamJS](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs)

> WebcamJS é uma pequena (~3K minificado e compactado) biblioteca *standalone* em JavaScript para capturar fotos a partir da câmera do seu computador, e entregá-los a você como JPEG ou PNG [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). As imagens podem ser exibidas em sua página web, rendido em uma tela, ou submetido ao seu servidor. WebcamJS usa [HTML5 getUserMedia](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html), mas proporciona um fallback automático e invisível através de Adobe Flash.

### Demonstração

```js
Webcam.set({
  width: 320,
  height: 240,
  image_format: 'jpeg',
  jpeg_quality: 90
});
Webcam.attach('#my_camera');

function take_snapshot() {
  // take snapshot and get image data
  Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
    // display results in page
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
      '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' +
      '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h2,
h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
form {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
form > input {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#results {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://pixlcore.com/demos/webcamjs/webcam.js"></script>
<div id="results">A imagem capturada aparece aqui...</div>

<h1>WebcamJS Página de teste</h1>
<h3>Demonstração de uma captura e apresentação em 320x240</h3>

<div id="my_camera"></div>

<form>
  <input type=button value="Tirar Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
</form>
```

### Enviar para o servidor

A função `Webcam.snap()` fornece a imagem por meio de um URI Dados via JavaScript, conforme vimos no exemplo em cima.

Contudo, também dispomos de uma forma de decodificar e enviar esses dados da imagem para o servidor através de uma chamada AJAX:

```js
var data_uri = Webcam.snap();

Webcam.upload( data_uri, 'meuScript.php', function(code, text) {
    // Upload concluído
    // 'code' contém o código da resposta HTTP enviado pelo servidor, ex. 200
    // 'text' contem o que o servidor enviou
});
```

No lado do servidor, os dados chegam tal como se tivessemos submetido um formulário com um campo `<input type="file" name="webcam">`, pelo que podemos simplesmente receber a imagem da seguinte forma:

```php
// verificações de segurança e outros
// ...
// mover o ficheiro recebido para o local pretendido
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'], 'webcam.jpg');
```

Se for necessário enviar mais dados para o servidor junto com a imagem, podemos faze-lo adicionando os mesmos na forma de *queryString*:

```js
var username = 'Bubu';
var image_fmt = 'jpeg';
var url = 'meuScript.php?username=' + username + '&format=' + image_fmt;
Webcam.upload( data_uri, url, function(code, text) {...} );
```

---

**Nota:** Existem muitas opções fornecidas pelo projeto WebcamJS e o mesmo está muito bem detalhado e recheado de exemplos de utilização no link do mesmo no GitHub.