# Tirar foto na web com tablet Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, html5, windows

### O que eu preciso

Quero fazer uma página onde o usuário possa clica em um botão, tirar uma foto com a câmera do *tablet*, visualizá-la e clicar no botão para salvá-la.

### O que eu já tentei

Já procurei utilizar o **HTML5** para isso:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

mas pelo que procurei e testei  aqui no *tablet*, essas tags só funcionam no iOs e Android.

Achei um tal de [BridgeIt](http://bridgeit.mobi/), mas não foi compatível, achei também um [artigo](http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera) sobre o assunto, copiei o código do tutorial mas nem no computador funcionou.

Comment: Você tentou as dicas [dessa outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23596/como-capturar-uma-foto-atrav%C3%A9s-da-webcam-do-usu%C3%A1rio-e-enviar-via-post)? Outra coisa: qual é o escopo maior do seu projeto? Pergunto isso porque se existirem outras interações com o uso e reconhecimento físico do tablet como meio, provavelmente se justificaria a criação de um aplicativo nativo ao invés do uso de uma página na Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 -** Você tentou através de uma solicitação XHR dentro de manipulador onchange do arquivo de entrada?

```
<input id="myFileInput" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">

var myInput = document.getElementById('myFileInput');

function sendPic() {
    var file = myInput.files[0];

    // Send file here either by adding it to a `FormData` object 
    // and sending that via XHR, or by simply passing the file into 
    // the `send` method of an XHR instance.
}

myInput.addEventListener('change', sendPic, false);
```

---

**2 -** Veja este tuto: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

---

**3 -** No iPhone iOS6 e Android ICS em diante, HTML5 tem a seguinte tag que permite que você tire fotos do seu dispositivo:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

`capture` pode assumir valores como câmera, câmera de vídeo e áudio.

Eu acho que essa tag definitivamente não irá funcionar no iOS5.

**4 -** Documentação: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/#example-1

Fonte:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581081/how-to-access-a-mobiles-camera-from-a-web-app

Comment: Deu certo?.....

Answer (score 1):

Ainda não existe uma maneira garantida de fazer acontecer em todas as situações por causa dos diferentes cenários de Browsers e configurações de ambiente que você pode encontrar. O mais Correto é escolher alguns cenários mais específicos que você pretende atender com a sua codificação e provavelmente vai depender mais da versão de browser que você pretende homologar para seu aplicativo do que do SO.

Atualmente muito se discute e se promove sobre o HTML5 e como você está usando Win 8.1, provavelmente seu browser terá suporte a ele.

Tente o material desse link:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Lembre que WinRT 8.1 é diferente do Win 8.1, portanto o suporte a browsers pode variar da versão do sistema e de quão atualizado está, o foco é o Browser e suas configurações. O IE é famoso por suas particularidades, verifique o suporte do seu browser ao html5.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a API [`MediaCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241124) para capturar uma imagem, vídeo e áudio. [**Aqui**](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622) têm um exemplo de utilização disponibilizado pela Microsoft para C++, C#, VB. NET e Javascript.

Esse exemplo mostra como fazer a captura de vídeo, gravação de áudio, tirar uma fotografia, entre outras coisas. Para fazer a captura de imagens foi utilizada as classes [`LowLagPhotoCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn278811) e [`LowLagPhotoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn297882).

Também é mostrado como capturar uma sequência de fotos usando as classes [`LowLagPhotoSequenceCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn278819) e [`LowLagPhotoSequenceControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn297902).

Para se acessar a pré-visualização das fotos capturadas pode se usar [`CapturePhoto.Thumbnail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn278796) e [`PhotoCapturedEventArgs.Thumbnail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn297822).

Artigo da Microsoft que podem ajudar:

- [Guia de início rápido: capturando vídeo usando o API MediaCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/hh452791)