# getUserMedia agora foi descontinuado em conexões não https?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Hoje pela manhã atualizei meu Google Chrome, no Ubuntu.

Quando fui fazer um teste na parte do sistema (local) em que tiramos foto da `webcam`, ao invés de exibir a mensagem de autorização para acessar a `webcam`, recebi a seguinte mensagem no console do navegador:

> getUserMedia() is deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Que traduzindo é

> getUserMedia() está obsoleta sobre as origens inseguras e suporte serão removidos no futuro. Você deve considerar a mudança seu aplicativo para uma origem segura, como HTTPS.

Todos os sistemas que utilizo `getUserMedia` terão de ser alterados para `HTTPS` por conta disso?

Qual é a razão de remover o suporte de `getUserMedia` em locais não-https?

## Atualização

Recebo hoje essa mensagem no meu Google Chrome:

> getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS

Já está bloqueando o uso da funcionalidade de capturar câmera/microfone do usuário.

E ainda assim gostaria de saber o qual é o perigo de se usar esses recursos em conexões não-https (não gosto de falar "inseguro").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O projeto Chromium anunciou essa mudança para se adaptar à nova normativa da W3C que determina que qualquer *recurso poderoso* tenha seu uso limitado através de ambientes seguros por autenticação.

A própria W3C admite que o simples fato de exigir HTTPS para tais recursos não é suficiente para garantir a segurança do usuário final, no entanto estabelece tal normativa como um pré-requisito para a construção de uma internet mais segura. A determinação é que qualquer aplicação que tenha acesso a dados sensíveis seja oferecida com o mínimo de segurança autenticada (HTTPS).

Apesar de a normativa não impedir desenvolvedores maliciosos de entregar conteúdo perigoso aos usuários finais, ela pelo menos tenta prevenir com maior frequência que ataques do tipo Homem-No-Meio injete scripts mal intencionados em sua página web para adquirir dados sensíveis de seus usuários.

Antes que tal mudança pudesse acontecer, precisava-se discutir o que caracteriza *recursos poderosos* no contexto Web. De forma resumida, ficou definido como recurso poderoso todo e qualquer código ofereça acesso a:

- Informações Sensíveis (Informações pessoais, credenciais, pagamentos, etc)
- Acesso a sensores (geolocation, webcam, camera, etc)
- Informações de outros dispositivos (Bluetooth, Wireless, etc)
- Armazenamentos em Sessão
- Recurso que possa solicitar a permissão do usuário
- Entre outros.

**Nota:** Acho que vale adicionar que o Chrome oferece uma flag que permite tratar sites inseguros como seguros para fins de testes. Basta executar o Chrome utilizando a flag `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="example.com"` (substituindo example.com com seu domínio de interesse).

---

Referências:

- [Definindo HTTP como Não-Seguro](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/marking-http-as-non-secure)
- [Definindo Recursos Poderosos em origens inseguras como obsoletos](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins)
- [Contexto de Segurança para Aplicações WEB - W3C](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/)