# Por que origens não-https são consideradas inseguras pelos navegadores?

Tags: ssl

Fiz uma pergunta agora questionando sobre um recurso que se tornou obsoleto em um determinado navegador, por que não se trata de uma origem com ssl.

Entendo perfeitamente que o `https` melhora a segurança do site, já que os dados [São criptografados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49564/4995).

Mas por que os navegadores utilizam o termo "insecure origin" (origem insegura) para origens que não utilizam o HTTPS, já que a segurança de um site **não depende** somente de um certificado SSL?

Temos muitas coisas que tornam um site inseguro:

- [Ataque XSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10921/ataques-xss-como-ocorre)
- [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php)
- [PHP Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699/o-que-%C3%A9-o-php-injection-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-dele-para-o-sql-injection-e-como-evit)

Dizer que falta de ssl torna o site inseguro não é exagero?

Comment: Não, não estou revoltado contra os navegadores.

Comment: A pergunta que gerou o questionamento dessa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95282/getusermedia-agora-ser%C3%A1-depreciado-em-conex%C3%B5es-n%C3%A3o-https

Comment: Ah, só para esclarecer o protocolo _SSL_ não melhora a segurança de todo, ele age como um suplemento para aumentar o nível de segurança. Se colocares _SSL_ injeções e _XSS_ continuam a ser possíveis, porque de forma geral, _SSL_ protege apenas o canal de transmissão *-*.

Comment: Então vejo que o @Edilson concorda comigo ;)

Comment: Outra coisa é, site com ou sem _SSL_ é basicamente a mesma coisa, porque se fores a ver, a maior parte dos sites usa apenas conexões do tipo _https_ em páginas onde o usuário fornece dados sensíveis e que por norma é-lhes exigido algum sigilo para que não sejam interceptados, "mas" caso os dados de entrada forem problemáticos e o sistema não for capaz de lidar com eles, vais ter exatamente os mesmos problemas.

Comment: Num mundo ideal não teria nada de inseguro num site HTTP. Bastaria não usar o HTTP para trafegar dados sigilosos ou ações que dependam de credenciais. Que problema teria um site de um restaurante ou clube de esgrima de usar HTTP para as páginas de acesso geral? Seria até mais eficiente a comunicação, inclusive.O problema é que agora tem até provedor que muda o conteúdo das páginas em troca de algum dinheiro ou coisa pior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Injeções PHP, SQL e similares ocorrem na camada da aplicação, que não é o escopo do SSL - este ocorre na camada de comunicação.

As preocupações a respeito da comunicação são claras e válidas. Por exemplo:

- Se sua comunicação com o servidor não é criptografada, [governos autoritários podem interceptar o conteúdo de suas comunicações](http://www.theverge.com/2015/4/10/8381827/china-great-cannon-firewall-web-censorship).
- Companhias com sérios problemas éticos [podem re-escrever o conteúdo transmitido](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20150825/13565132062/att-injecting-ads-into-wi-fi-hotspot-data-streams.shtml), trocando por exemplo conteúdo por anúncios.
- Ataques *man-in-the-middle*: Qualquer servidor intermediário entre os dois pontos pode interceptar e ler seu conteúdo.

Dada a ubiquidade do uso da internet para transmissão de dados de processos sigilosos (acesso a contas bancárias, dados médicos, etc.), a guarantia de tráfego seguro possui alta prioridade - por isso companhias estão adotando SSL como padrão, e sites abertos considerados inseguros.

Comment: Obrigado, agora sim esclareceu o paranauê

Answer (score -1):

"Nós, da Equipe de Segurança Chrome, propomos mudar seu UX para exibir origens não-seguras como afirmativamente não segura.
Temos a intenção de conceber e iniciar a implantação de um plano de transição para o Chrome em 2015.

O objetivo desta proposta é mostrar mais claramente aos usuários que HTTP
não oferece segurança de dados".

Sites HTTP vai continuar a funcionar; no momento não temos planos para bloqueá-los no Chrome. Tudo o que vai mudar são os indicadores de segurança.

https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/marking-http-as-non-secure

Comment: Nem o HTTPS oferece segurança de dados, se o site foi programado sem tomar cuidado com os outros itens citados na pergunta. Ainda continuo achando que isso é um exagero. Daqui a pouco ninguém vai mais entrar em um site sem https :|

Comment: No link, são mostrados alguns critérios. Creio que se voce adotar os necessários seu site pode sair dessa lista negra.

Comment: @AlanTuring citar uma frase, e passar um _link_ não é propriamente esclarecedor, e isso já é bem sabido.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, lendo o artigo deles, acho que é apenas uma forma de tentar obrigar os sites a melhorarem a segurança.

Comment: @Edilson sempre existem os Haterz kkkkk