# ImgSelect: MediaStream stop is not a function

Tags: javascript

Eu fiz essa pergunta aqui no Stackoverflow em Português:

[getUserMedia agora foi descontinuado em conexões não https?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95282/getusermedia-agora-foi-descontinuado-em-conex%C3%B5es-n%C3%A3o-https)

E notei que, depois de ter subido um sistema para o servidor, a câmera parou de funcionar. O domínio possui o HTTPS.

Agora estou recebendo o seguinte erro no Plugin chamado `ImgSelect`:

> imgSelect.min.js:249 Uncaught TypeError: n.stop is not a function

Ou seja, essa função, que existia antes, não existe mais.

Anteriormente, soube que o método `MediaStream.stop` seria removido, pois estava descontinuado.

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: `MediaStreamTrack.stop()`

Comment: Não é isso @MarcoAurélioDeleu.

Comment: Esse negativo (independente de quem tenha o dado) aí não tem motivo algum.

Comment: Dei +1 para igualar. =D

Comment: Valeu. Tá difícil a vida aqui :D

Comment: Nem fale. Eu fui advertido por dar muitos votos negativos a uma pessoa só.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei conseguindo resolver o problema sozinho. Não sou a favor de alterar código-fonte de qualquer coisa, mas nesse caso eu alterei o código que do ImgSelect que tinha esse trecho:

```
if (n) n.stop();
```

Para isso

```
 if (n) {
     n.stop ? n.stop() : n.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
 }
```

Ainda não tinha nada na internet sobre o assunto, por isso decidi perguntar aqui no SOPT.