# Como configurar SSL (HTTPS) no Apache localmente?

Tags: apache, ssl, https

Para fins de testes, necessito localmente configurar o meu Apache para aceitar acessar determinado site configurado no Virtualhost com SSL.

Creio que saber de alguma forma configurar o SSL em ambiente local seja muito útil para quem trabalha com desenvolvimento de algum site web onde é necessário acessar a webcam, por exemplo, visto [que esses recursos foram recentementes bloqueados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95282/getusermedia-agora-ser%C3%A1-depreciado-em-conex%C3%B5es-n%C3%A3o-https?noredirect=1&lq=1) em navegadores com conexão "insegura" (sem HTTPS). Assim, para realizar testes locais, eu precisaria ter o apache configurado com SSL para poder testar esses recursos.

Sendo assim, como posso configurar o meu Apache para aceitar acesso com SSL localmente?

Existe alguma maneira de meu site local `http://localhost` poder ser acessado como `https://localhost`?

Comment: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Configuracao-do-SSL-no-Apache?pagina=3 Viva...

Comment: Acho que da forma que está, é ampla.

Comment: @MagicHat pow, não é ampla... É só gerar as chaves, apontar no apache pelo VirtualHost e reiniciar... Eu não fiz a resposta porque estou com preguiça, mas não é um bicho de sete cabeças

Comment: Ah sei lá, seu modo de pensar é diferente do meu, por isso não votei, se a community pensar como vc boas... mas são muitos passos, e vc nem menciona sua plataforma... e alias o que é `lovslmmyr`?

Comment: @MagicHat uma nova língua. Ela é escrita por programadores que não estão acostumado a usar o notebook direito, kkkkkk

Comment: Você quer fazer isso no linux ou no windows ?

Comment: Veja o vídeo, pois nele ensina como fazer certinho só seguir os passos.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfRy5coRcCE&t=71s

Comment: @MagicHat para os dois seria  importante, mas meu foco mesmo é o linux. Mas outros usuários poderão se interessar pelo Windows.

Comment: Tem um tutorial aqui, estou seguindo para adicionar numa maquina com windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost